# Automatic redirection to another website

Tags: malware

As soon as I open a webpage, I am redirected to another site. I have an antivirus on my PC, but it has not been able to do anything to stop this. I have reseted my browser settings (Chrome) and checked for any malicious extensions also, but no avail. There is nothing there. I have checked my boot-log files, but have found nothing malicious.

I am either taken to this link:
`https://apply.standardchartered.co.in/credit-card?selectedCardId=5&se=VCommission_CC_Mailers&cp=Platinum_june&ag=32178&kd=rx_mailer_TBWA`

Or to that link:

```
http://indianews.com-3v3v86d2ck76zvhihg7mm669k4znsfoct.pw/index2.html?voluumdata=vid..00000003-5908-4abf-8000-000000000000__vpid..875e1800-6a65-11e5-8bf7-68951d3e011c__caid..220bd123-58b3-475b-95ad-6a591acd71f6__rt..R__lid..e84c87f6-7600-461e-9f5d-1c4ff52dce63__oid1..e5caf233-f36c-40b7-9b0a-8cadf6a9be48__var1..10%5C_%5C36691656%5C_%5C6e08080b-c59f-418a-87b9-aeb7bdb3bf7a__var2..354802__var3..aedge__rd..srv2trking%5C.%5Ccom__aid..__sid..&clickid=10_36691656_6e08080b-c59f-418a-87b9-aeb7bdb3bf7a&siteid=354802&source=aedge
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You have this problem with all websites or just specific websites?

Comment: Does this also happen with other browsers? And what OS are you using?

Comment: Use [Junkware Removal Tool](http://bleepingcomputer.com/download/junkware-removal-tool/) and [Adwcleaner](http://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)

Comment: Like @Nikhil_CV wrote, use AdwCleaner. It detecs also browser extensions but you should also check them manually.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have adware installed. It usually comes with installing unlicensed commercial software products.  I'd suggest getting the trial version of a product such as [kaspersky](http://www.kaspersky.com/) or [nod32](http://www.eset.com/) and run a scan when in safe mode as it is more likely that the adware doesn't launch.

If the adware is still in place use the(rescue) live CDs of the above products.

Answer (score 0):

best soulation is installing [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/),it is free and powerful and will kill all adwares on your browser